# Sorting in ascending and descending order Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can implement sorting not only by increasing, but also by decreasing?
Here is the code in which it can only be sorted by an upward name and an identifier.
How can I change it so that it can still be sorted in descending order?

```
sortType(sort: string){
    if(sort === 'id') {
        this.projects = this.projects.sort(this.sortByID); 
        console.log(this.projects);
    }

    if(sort === 'name') {
        this.sprWellpads = this.projects.sort(this.sortByName); 
        console.log(this.projects);
    }
}

sortByName(a: Project, b: Project){
  if(a.name > b.name)  return 1
    else if (a.name == b.name)return 0
  else return -1
}

sortByID(a: Project, b: Project){
    return parseInt(a.id.toString())-parseInt(b.id.toString());
}
```

html:

```
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortType('id')" [class.active]="sortBy === 'id'" ><a class="title">ID⬇</a></a>
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortType('name')" [class.active]="sortBy === 'name'"><a class="title">Name⬇</a></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To order an object array with TypeScript:

```
let values = ["B_Value", "C_Value", "A_Value"];

// Ascending

values.sort((a,b) => 0 - (a > b ? -1 : 1));

// Descending

values.sort((a,b) => 0 - (a > b ? 1 : -1));
```